Powershell script to automate run exe file
I have this script that is designed to automatically run an exe file in administrator mode everytime the user turn on the computer and login.
# Get the directory of the script
$scriptPath = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

# Define the path to the exe
$exePath = Join-Path -Path $scriptPath -ChildPath "MyExeFile.exe"

# Check if the exe exists
if (-not (Test-Path $exePath)) {
    Write-Error "MyExeFile.exe not found in the script directory."
    exit 1
}

# Name for the scheduled task
$taskName = "Run Exe File on Login"

# Create a new scheduled task action
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $exePath

# Create trigger to run at system startup
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup

# Set up principal to run with highest privileges
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest

# Create the scheduled task
$task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Principal $principal

# Register the scheduled task
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -InputObject $task -Force

# Run the task immediately
Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName

When I run the script as administrator, it runs and there's no problem appeared but when I restart the computer and then loging in, the exe file isn't run at all.
This is the first time I ever scripting with powershell, I'd be very grateful if any expert could have a look at it and point out the problem or give me some suggestions to find the problem.
After checking the suggestion from Scheduled Task Powershell Script - Runs OK as user account, but not as SYSTEM. I found out that: The Script does run, however, in the Task Scheduler Library  it set as Queue, so I need to make it run manually in Task Scheduler Library.
But even so, when I try to restart the computer, the exe file still isnt executed.
When I check for the action, it seems right since I did run that action in cmd myself and the exe file is run as expect.
The action is showed as below:

I also have checked for the triggered condition, it also seems fine too:

In the History, there's also the record to show that, the task actually does run up on computer started:

So my suspect right now is probably the script read the action wrongly so it cant run the exe file ?

So I've figured out the problem in case if some one encounter the same thing in the next few years. The script does run, however only the exe file is run in task manager, but the program is not open. The reason is because I run it as SYSTEM in the line $principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest, after I change "SYSTEM" to $principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId $currentUser -LogonType Interactive -RunLevel Highest, the script run as I want.
Additionally, the task from my script will be set as Queue in the Task Library, I've adjusted it so it will run right away up on running:
# Get the directory of the script
$scriptPath = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

# Define the path to the exe
$exePath = Join-Path -Path $scriptPath -ChildPath "MyFile.exe"

# Check if the exe exists
if (-not (Test-Path $exePath)) {
    Write-Error "MyFile.exe not found in the script directory."
    exit 1
}

# Create a batch file to run the exe
$batchPath = Join-Path -Path $scriptPath -ChildPath "RunServiceMonitor.bat"
@"
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
start "" "$exePath"
"@ | Out-File -FilePath $batchPath -Encoding ASCII

# Name for the scheduled task
$taskName = "Run Ingeteam Service Monitor"

# Create a new scheduled task action
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $batchPath

# Create trigger to run at user logon
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn

# Set up principal to run as the current user with highest privileges
$currentUser = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId $currentUser -LogonType Interactive -RunLevel Highest

# Create the scheduled task
$task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Principal $principal

# Register the scheduled task
try {
    Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -InputObject $task -Force
    Write-Host "Scheduled task '$taskName' registered successfully."
}
catch {
    Write-Error "Failed to register scheduled task: $_"
    exit 1
}

# Run the task immediately
try {
    Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName
    Write-Host "Scheduled task '$taskName' started successfully."
}
catch {
    Write-Error "Failed to start scheduled task: $_"
}

# Wait for a moment to allow the task to start
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

# Check if the process is running
$process = Get-Process -Name "ProcessName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($process) {
    Write-Host "Process is now running with PID: $($process.Id)"
}
else {
    Write-Warning "Process does not appear to be running. Please check the Task Scheduler for more information."
}

# Display the task status
$taskInfo = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName
Write-Host "Current task status: $($taskInfo.State)"

# If the task is still queued, try to run it again
if ($taskInfo.State -eq "Queued") {
    Write-Host "Task is queued. Attempting to run it again..."
    Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    $taskInfo = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName
    Write-Host "Updated task status: $($taskInfo.State)"
}

